# Tabbed Activity Page Title not showing

Tags: java, android, android-tabbed-activity

[This is what I was trying to do, The "Tab One" "Tab Two" as my Tabbed Page Title. Ignore the Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQLe.png)

I created an app that uses tabbed activity, I used the preset tabbed activity in android studio and modified it to my use. But I'm having a problem in showing the tabbed title. I'm working only on 2 tabs for now but i'm planning to add more as I progress.

Here is the codes for my Tabbed Activity Class

```
public class StudLearnTab extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    String key;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_content);

        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("keys",key);
                    fragment_tabbed_content tab1 = new fragment_tabbed_content();
                    tab1.setArguments(bundle);
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    fragment_tabbed_activity tab2 = new fragment_tabbed_activity();
                    return tab2;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return "Content";
                case 1:
                    return "Try Yourself";
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

My Fragments only contains the constructor and createview but I'll included it here for reference. Both fragments are almost the same.

```
public class fragment_tabbed_activity extends Fragment {


    public fragment_tabbed_activity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed_activity, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: need to show title in toolbar or tab?

Comment: please attach screenshot so we can understand what exactly you need.

Comment: I already attached a Screenshot of what I was going to do, the thing that was not showing was the Page Title, sorry I got confused about the page and tabbed title.

Comment: did you forgot to call `TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)` ?